# Switing between images on Gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've coded a gallery with jQuery, CSS & HTML, and I want to add in next image and previous image buttons, so I have added them to the page and I have made functions for them but I don't know how I will do this. Here is my code and if any body knows any good way of doing this I'd be happy! Thanks!
*edit* I haven't received a response so I'll try and give more information, I'm trying to get arrows on the left and right hand side of my image so I can go to previous and next image and I don't know how to do this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.thumbnail').click(function(){
  $('.backdrop').animate({'opacity':'.5'}, 300, 'linear');
  $('.box').animate({'opacity' : '1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
  $('.box, .selectors, .backdrop').css('display', 'block');
  $('.box').html('<img class="boximg" src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '">');

  //$('.box').html('<img class="boximg" src="' + src + '">');
 });
 $('.nextimg').click(function(){
  $('.box').html('<img class="boximg" src="' + '">');
 });

 $('.previmg').click(function(){
  $('.box').html('<img class="boximg" src="'+'">');
 });

 $('.backdrop').click(function(){
  close_box();
 });
});

$(document).keydown(function(event){
if (event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13){
 close_box();
};
});

function close_box(){
$('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity': '0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
 $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
 $('.selectors').css('display', 'none');
});
}
```

```css
.backdrop{
position: absolute;
display: none;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background-color: #000;
opacity: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.box{
position: absolute;
display: none;
background-color: white;
opacity: 0;
top: 10%;
left: 10%;
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
border-radius: 13px;
}

.close{
float: right;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.boximg {
position: absolute;
top: 3%;
left: 2%;
width: 96%;
height: 94%;
}

.thumbnail{
 border-radius: 30px;
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
}

.selectors{
 display: none;
}

.nextimg{
position: absolute;
right: 3%;
top: 50%;
}

.previmg{
position: absolute;
left: 3%;
top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="images">
  <img class="thumbnail" src="urlttr.jpeg">
  <img class="thumbnail" src="http://www.hdwallpapers.eu/wp/sci-fi-planet-background-1920x1080.jpg">
  <img class="thumbnail" src="http://www.wallpapersdb.org/wallpapers/beach/sunrise_1920x1080.jpg">
  <img class="thumbnail" src="http://free-hq-wallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/New-York-Sunset-1920x1080.jpg">
 </div>
 <div class="backdrop"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="selectors">
  <image class="nextimg" src="right_arrow.png">
  <image class="previmg" src="left_arrow.png">
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your code to jsfiddle, [I came up with this as a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/6du3r816/1/).

```
<div class="images">
    <!-- In the a-href you put the path to the big sized image. In the image src the small thumb path. -->
    <a href="/city-q-c-640-480-3.jpg">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="/city-q-c-640-480-3.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <a href="/sci-fi-planet-background-1920x1080.jpg">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="/sci-fi-planet-background-1920x1080.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <a href="/sunrise_1920x1080.jpg">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="/sunrise_1920x1080.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <a href="/New-York-Sunset-1920x1080.jpg">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="/New-York-Sunset-1920x1080.jpg"/>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="backdrop"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="selectors">
    <img class="nextimg" src="right_arrow.png"/>
    <img class="previmg" src="left_arrow.png"/>
</div>
```

You can see there, that I surrounded the thumbs with a-tags - you could also instead use a data attribute or something similar to add the path for the big version of the images.

```
$(function() {
    var $currentImageLink; // the current a tag

    $('.images a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $currentImageLink = $(this);

        $('.backdrop').animate({'opacity':'.5'}, 300, 'linear');
        $('.box').animate({'opacity' : '1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
        $('.box, .selectors, .backdrop').css('display', 'block');
        $('.box').html('<img class="boximg" src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">');
    });

    $('.nextimg').click(function() {
        $currentImageLink = $currentImageLink.next('a');
        if (0 == $currentImageLink.length) {
            $currentImageLink = $('.images a:first-child');
        }
        $('.box').html('<img class="boximg" src="' + $currentImageLink.attr('href') + '">');
    });

    $('.previmg').click(function() {
        $currentImageLink = $currentImageLink.prev('a');
        if (0 == $currentImageLink.length) {
            $currentImageLink = $('.images a:last-child');
        }
        $('.box').html('<img class="boximg" src="' + $currentImageLink.attr('href') +'">');
    });

    $('.backdrop').click(function() {
        close_box();
    });
});

$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        close_box();
    }
});

function close_box() {
    $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity': '0'}, 300, 'linear', function() {
        $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
        $('.selectors').css('display', 'none');
    });
}
```

Furthermore I added the variable $currentImageLink in which I put always the current link element, that is shown at that moment in your gallery.
In the functions for next and prev that variable is filled with the next/prev link element. If there is no such element, it will become the first or last element.

Depending on what you want to do with the gallery, maybe you could then also make the images fade-out/-in or preload the big images.

Comment: Thank You! But what does $currentImageLink = $currentImageLink.next('a'); and $(function() {}) do? I thought for the $(function(){}); you had to make it $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: $(function(){})

is just a short version of

     $(document).ready(function(){})
-
    $currentImageLink.next('a')
searches for the next a element

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6du3r816/2/ - (there was a black thing in the middle of the thumbs) -  you can remove it with removing the spaces between the a tag and the img tags

Comment: Yeah, instead I just set the text decoration to none ;p